# Create Normal Distribution by removing data

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I am looking for a way to create a normal distribution by **removing** rows from a variable in a data frame. I only want to REMOVE data, not transform data with multiplication. The normal distribution should have it's mean at 3 and range from 1 to 5. Below you can find a histogrm.

I would also want to know which of the rows I should remove either by the rows number [i,] or using an ID variable – because I need to remove this data in another data frame as well. This is my data:

```
  [1] 2.6 1.1 3.6 1.5 3.6 1.5 1.4 1.1 1.4 1.1 2.0 2.5 3.1 2.9 3.2 1.3 3.5 2.7 1.0 1.7 4.1 2.8 3.2 3.2 1.6 2.0 3.1 2.8 3.9 2.0 3.9 1.7 1.8 1.6 2.3 3.0 1.9 2.3 1.6 2.7 1.6 4.0 1.3 1.1 2.0 3.4
 [47] 2.6 2.3 2.1 2.3 1.8 1.2 1.8 3.1 2.5 2.2 2.9 2.2 1.1 1.2 1.8 4.2 1.6 3.3 2.1 3.2 3.1 1.9 1.0 2.0 2.2 1.9 2.8 3.6 2.6 1.7 2.6 1.9 2.2 1.6 4.1 1.8 2.1 2.4 2.5 1.7 2.7 1.9 2.5 2.0 1.9 3.8
 [93] 2.6 1.7 1.4 3.7 1.0 2.4 1.8 1.2 1.4 2.5 1.4 3.8 4.2 4.3 3.7 4.0 3.0 1.8 4.0 4.2 2.8 2.8 1.2 3.3 2.4 2.3 3.0 1.6 2.0 4.5 2.0 2.2 2.1 2.4 1.0 2.4 3.6 2.0 2.9 2.0 4.1 2.4 3.1 2.7 2.3 1.4
[139] 1.8 2.3 3.2 2.8 1.6 2.5 2.9 1.0 1.6 2.7 2.8 3.5 1.1 1.8 3.6 2.9 1.4 1.2 3.5 3.1 3.4 3.1 2.0 3.3 2.8 2.3 3.6 3.3 3.5 1.7 1.3 1.6 2.3 1.3 2.9 1.0 1.3 1.8 1.7 1.3 3.5 2.2 2.2 3.6 3.0 1.0
[185] 2.5 2.9 2.2 2.4 2.1 1.0 1.3 2.0 3.3 3.1 3.2 2.3 2.1 2.7 3.0 3.7 3.1 2.7 4.5 3.0 1.6 1.9 3.1 3.6 1.6 1.2 2.0 1.3 1.6 4.7 2.0 1.4 3.6 2.5 1.3 4.0 1.6 1.4 1.9 3.6 2.5 2.9 3.7 2.4 4.6 3.7
[231] 2.2 4.3 3.7 1.5 1.5 2.5 4.0 4.3 3.5 2.7 2.0 2.7 3.8 1.3 3.1 2.2 1.8 1.5 3.3 2.9 1.5 3.3 1.3 1.7 2.1 1.7 3.0 2.2 4.0 1.3 4.3 1.5 2.5 2.3 1.5 1.6 4.4 1.3 2.4 1.8 2.7 1.6 1.5 3.4 4.0 2.5
[277] 2.3 2.4 2.5 1.6 2.8 1.8 3.3 1.7 1.9 2.3 2.4 3.5 2.0 4.3 1.4 2.3 2.8 3.7 4.1 4.0 2.7 2.5 2.9 4.1 2.2 2.4 3.0 1.5 1.4 2.0 2.5 2.2 3.3 2.2 1.0 3.8 3.0 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.9 2.2 1.4 1.7 4.0 2.3
[323] 4.4 2.7 2.6 2.7 3.4 2.5 3.9 2.5 2.0 4.3 2.9 3.6 2.0 1.7 2.6 2.2 2.2 3.0 2.0 3.3 1.2 2.8 3.2 4.8 4.2 1.6 1.8 4.2 3.6 2.4 3.6 1.5 3.0 3.6 1.1 3.1 2.8 2.6 3.8 2.1 1.4 3.3 3.0 3.8 2.5 3.8
[369] 2.1 1.5 2.7 2.3 2.3 2.2 2.8 1.9 3.7 3.1 2.8 1.4 1.8 3.2
```

This is a histogram of this data.
[image: Histogram]

Comment: How are you defining whether it is a normal distribution?

Comment: I'd do the Shapiro Wilk Test.

Comment: I'm not a statistician but Shapiro-Wilk tells you the probability that a _population_ is normally distributed, given a sample. But once you remove data you do not have a real sample - you have just made it up - so the data tells you nothing about the population. Your question is really asking a) what is the best algorithm/method for removing data from a sample to create a normal distribution, and b) what is an appropriate method to check if it's normal? Once that's established, the code will be trivial. On that basis it might be better on Cross Validated - I am going to vote to migrate it.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! Can I help in some way? I am relatively new here, so I am not familiar with migrating posts.

Comment: You can read more about migration [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: What is your goal in doing this?

Comment: You can remove all the rows by one, picked at random, and claim the data is normally distributed. As @StephanKolassa said, what is your purpose here? Otherwise, arbitrary solutions like the one suggested are valid answers to your question.

Comment: It is difficult to conceive of a legitimate statistical application of such a method.  Why not just make the numbers up?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @ShawnHemelstrand that it doesn't seem like a good idea to do what you are trying to do.  However, if you really want to do it, one way would be to use a "rejection sampler" approach.  You can't get a normal distribution exactly because you have no negative values, but you can come fairly close as follows.

First, get a density estimate of your current sample.  This involves a bit of judgment in how much smoothing to do, but I'll use the default:

```
obs <- c(2.6, 1.1, 3.6, 1.5, 3.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.1, 1.4, 1.1, 2, 2.5, 3.1, 
  2.9, 3.2, 1.3, 3.5, 2.7, 1, 1.7, 4.1, 2.8, 3.2, 3.2, 1.6, 2, 
  3.1, 2.8, 3.9, 2, 3.9, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 2.3, 3, 1.9, 2.3, 1.6, 
  2.7, 1.6, 4, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3.4, 2.6, 2.3, 2.1, 2.3, 1.8, 1.2, 
  1.8, 3.1, 2.5, 2.2, 2.9, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8, 4.2, 1.6, 3.3, 2.1, 
  3.2, 3.1, 1.9, 1, 2, 2.2, 1.9, 2.8, 3.6, 2.6, 1.7, 2.6, 1.9, 
  2.2, 1.6, 4.1, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.5, 1.7, 2.7, 1.9, 2.5, 2, 1.9, 
  3.8, 2.6, 1.7, 1.4, 3.7, 1, 2.4, 1.8, 1.2, 1.4, 2.5, 1.4, 3.8, 
  4.2, 4.3, 3.7, 4, 3, 1.8, 4, 4.2, 2.8, 2.8, 1.2, 3.3, 2.4, 2.3, 
  3, 1.6, 2, 4.5, 2, 2.2, 2.1, 2.4, 1, 2.4, 3.6, 2, 2.9, 2, 4.1, 
  2.4, 3.1, 2.7, 2.3, 1.4, 1.8, 2.3, 3.2, 2.8, 1.6, 2.5, 2.9, 1, 
  1.6, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 1.1, 1.8, 3.6, 2.9, 1.4, 1.2, 3.5, 3.1, 3.4, 
  3.1, 2, 3.3, 2.8, 2.3, 3.6, 3.3, 3.5, 1.7, 1.3, 1.6, 2.3, 1.3, 
  2.9, 1, 1.3, 1.8, 1.7, 1.3, 3.5, 2.2, 2.2, 3.6, 3, 1, 2.5, 2.9, 
  2.2, 2.4, 2.1, 1, 1.3, 2, 3.3, 3.1, 3.2, 2.3, 2.1, 2.7, 3, 3.7, 
  3.1, 2.7, 4.5, 3, 1.6, 1.9, 3.1, 3.6, 1.6, 1.2, 2, 1.3, 1.6, 
  4.7, 2, 1.4, 3.6, 2.5, 1.3, 4, 1.6, 1.4, 1.9, 3.6, 2.5, 2.9, 
  3.7, 2.4, 4.6, 3.7, 2.2, 4.3, 3.7, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 4, 4.3, 3.5, 
  2.7, 2, 2.7, 3.8, 1.3, 3.1, 2.2, 1.8, 1.5, 3.3, 2.9, 1.5, 3.3, 
  1.3, 1.7, 2.1, 1.7, 3, 2.2, 4, 1.3, 4.3, 1.5, 2.5, 2.3, 1.5, 
  1.6, 4.4, 1.3, 2.4, 1.8, 2.7, 1.6, 1.5, 3.4, 4, 2.5, 2.3, 2.4, 
  2.5, 1.6, 2.8, 1.8, 3.3, 1.7, 1.9, 2.3, 2.4, 3.5, 2, 4.3, 1.4, 
  2.3, 2.8, 3.7, 4.1, 4, 2.7, 2.5, 2.9, 4.1, 2.2, 2.4, 3, 1.5, 
  1.4, 2, 2.5, 2.2, 3.3, 2.2, 1, 3.8, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.9, 2.2, 
  1.4, 1.7, 4, 2.3, 4.4, 2.7, 2.6, 2.7, 3.4, 2.5, 3.9, 2.5, 2, 
  4.3, 2.9, 3.6, 2, 1.7, 2.6, 2.2, 2.2, 3, 2, 3.3, 1.2, 2.8, 3.2, 
  4.8, 4.2, 1.6, 1.8, 4.2, 3.6, 2.4, 3.6, 1.5, 3, 3.6, 1.1, 3.1, 
  2.8, 2.6, 3.8, 2.1, 1.4, 3.3, 3, 3.8, 2.5, 3.8, 2.1, 1.5, 2.7, 
  2.3, 2.3, 2.2, 2.8, 1.9, 3.7, 3.1, 2.8, 1.4, 1.8, 3.2)

dens <- density(obs)
densfn <- approxfun(dens$x, dens$y, rule = 2)
```

Next, get a density function for the target distribution, N(3, 1).  This will have about 95% of the data between 1 and 5.  As others have mentioned, you can't get 100%.

```
normdensfn <- function(x) dnorm(x, mean = 3, sd = 1)
```

Now figure out where the observed data has the smallest density compared to the target distribution.  You want to keep all of those, and reject some values where it has too much density.  The trouble is, the observed data has zero density outside a finite range, so you can't do a perfect job of this.  Concentrate on the range from 2 to 4:

```r
x <- seq(2, 4, len=200)
maxratio <- max(normdensfn(x)/densfn(x))

curve(densfn(x), from = 1, to = 5, col = "red")
curve(normdensfn(x)/maxratio, add = TRUE, col = "blue")
legend("topright", col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1, 
       legend = c("observed", "Scaled N(3, 1)"))
```

[image]

By concentrating on the range from 2 to 4, we're going to undersample from 4 to 5.

```r
# Generate uniforms U for each observation, and keep the observation
# if U < normdensfn(x)/maxratio/densfn(x) 

keep <- runif(length(obs)) < normdensfn(obs)/maxratio/densfn(obs)
plot(density(obs[keep]), col = "green")
curve(normdensfn, add=TRUE, col = "blue")
legend("topright", col=c("green", "blue"), lty=1, 
       legend = c("kept", "N(3, 1)"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

### Simulating the Data Splits

I recreated your data in R and split your data three times: first by 100 rows, then 200 rows, then finally 300 rows. After I plotted them in histograms and arranged them on a grid to compare them:

```
#### Read Data ####
df <- read.table(text = "2.6 1.1 3.6 1.5 3.6 1.5 1.4 1.1 1.4 1.1 2.0 2.5 3.1 2.9 3.2 1.3 3.5 2.7 1.0 1.7 4.1 2.8 3.2 3.2 1.6 2.0 3.1 2.8 3.9 2.0 3.9 1.7 1.8 1.6 2.3 3.0 1.9 2.3 1.6 2.7 1.6 4.0 1.3 1.1 2.0 3.4 2.6 2.3 2.1 2.3 1.8 1.2 1.8 3.1 2.5 2.2 2.9 2.2 1.1 1.2 1.8 4.2 1.6 3.3 2.1 3.2 3.1 1.9 1.0 2.0 2.2 1.9 2.8 3.6 2.6 1.7 2.6 1.9 2.2 1.6 4.1 1.8 2.1 2.4 2.5 1.7 2.7 1.9 2.5 2.0 1.9 3.8 2.6 1.7 1.4 3.7 1.0 2.4 1.8 1.2 1.4 2.5 1.4 3.8 4.2 4.3 3.7 4.0 3.0 1.8 4.0 4.2 2.8 2.8 1.2 3.3 2.4 2.3 3.0 1.6 2.0 4.5 2.0 2.2 2.1 2.4 1.0 2.4 3.6 2.0 2.9 2.0 4.1 2.4 3.1 2.7 2.3 1.4 1.8 2.3 3.2 2.8 1.6 2.5 2.9 1.0 1.6 2.7 2.8 3.5 1.1 1.8 3.6 2.9 1.4 1.2 3.5 3.1 3.4 3.1 2.0 3.3 2.8 2.3 3.6 3.3 3.5 1.7 1.3 1.6 2.3 1.3 2.9 1.0 1.3 1.8 1.7 1.3 3.5 2.2 2.2 3.6 3.0 1.0 2.5 2.9 2.2 2.4 2.1 1.0 1.3 2.0 3.3 3.1 3.2 2.3 2.1 2.7 3.0 3.7 3.1 2.7 4.5 3.0 1.6 1.9 3.1 3.6 1.6 1.2 2.0 1.3 1.6 4.7 2.0 1.4 3.6 2.5 1.3 4.0 1.6 1.4 1.9 3.6 2.5 2.9 3.7 2.4 4.6 3.7 2.2 4.3 3.7 1.5 1.5 2.5 4.0 4.3 3.5 2.7 2.0 2.7 3.8 1.3 3.1 2.2 1.8 1.5 3.3 2.9 1.5 3.3 1.3 1.7 2.1 1.7 3.0 2.2 4.0 1.3 4.3 1.5 2.5 2.3 1.5 1.6 4.4 1.3 2.4 1.8 2.7 1.6 1.5 3.4 4.0 2.5 2.3 2.4 2.5 1.6 2.8 1.8 3.3 1.7 1.9 2.3 2.4 3.5 2.0 4.3 1.4 2.3 2.8 3.7 4.1 4.0 2.7 2.5 2.9 4.1 2.2 2.4 3.0 1.5 1.4 2.0 2.5 2.2 3.3 2.2 1.0 3.8 3.0 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.9 2.2 1.4 1.7 4.0 2.3 4.4 2.7 2.6 2.7 3.4 2.5 3.9 2.5 2.0 4.3 2.9 3.6 2.0 1.7 2.6 2.2 2.2 3.0 2.0 3.3 1.2 2.8 3.2 4.8 4.2 1.6 1.8 4.2 3.6 2.4 3.6 1.5 3.0 3.6 1.1 3.1 2.8 2.6 3.8 2.1 1.4 3.3 3.0 3.8 2.5 3.8 2.1 1.5 2.7 2.3 2.3 2.2 2.8 1.9 3.7 3.1 2.8 1.4 1.8 3.2",
header = F,
sep = " ")

#### Make Tibble and Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
tibble <- df %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  as_tibble()

#### Split 1 ####
short.1 <- tibble %>% 
  slice(100:382)

#### Split 2 ####
short.2 <- tibble %>% 
  slice(200:382)

#### Split 3 ####
short.3 <- tibble %>% 
  slice(300:382)


#### Make Histograms ####
raw.data <- gghistogram(tibble$value,
            bins = 8,
            title = "Raw Data")
short.data1 <- gghistogram(short.1$value,
            bins = 8,
            title = "Raw Data -100 Rows")
short.data2 <- gghistogram(short.2$value,
                           bins=8,
                           title = "Raw Data - 200 Rows")
short.data3 <- gghistogram(short.3$value,
                           bins=8,
                           title = "Raw Data - 300 Rows")

#### Arrange Data into 4 Plot Grid ####
ggarrange(raw.data,
          short.data1,
          short.data2,
          short.data3)
```

### Plot Interpretation

You can see below that removing the rows doesn't automatically fix the problem and is a great way to remove important info about your real distribution. In the last split, you have essentially destroyed a ton of power you would have otherwise had in your design had listwise deletion not been employed:

[image]

This would be especially damning if you ran some form of inferential test on the data. For example, if you were comparing the means of this group and another with a t-test, the shifting mean and SD here would cause issues of interpretation, and this would vary a lot by what distribution you are working with:

```
#### Mean Values ####
mean(tibble$value) # 2.519
mean(short.1$value) # 2.594
mean(short.2$value) # 2.654
mean(short.3$value) # 2.719

#### SD Values ####
sd(tibble$value) # .910
sd(short.1$value) # .925
sd(short.2$value) # .938
sd(short.3$value) # .886
```

Of course if you have defensible reasons for removing these values, feel free to do so, but always remember that you should have a pretty strong case if somebody asks why. There are also alternatives to redistributing data you already mentioned, such as applying a log or square root transformation to skewed data distributions, but these are not miracle solutions and may present their own problems which should be checked as well.

### One Last Takeaway

You have a final thing to consider...if you remove a ton of values from this data, is it truly representative of what it measured? Consider for example a class of students who were going to take a test today. Let's say the teacher decides to remove the first row of students in the class, forces them to take a standardized test, and then runs descriptive stats on the test scores of those people remaining. There are two issues here. First, what were these first row students like? Maybe they sat at the front because they were overachievers or they learned better by being closer to the teacher. This would undoubtedly bias the data and make it less generalizable. Second, do the descriptives truly represent normal classes if a large portion of normal students go missing? I can't imagine the average test score from this example would be reflective of monthly academic achievement. These are important points to consider.

Answer (score 4):

We can down-select $n$ data points from an initial data set $X$ in a way that optimally fits a probability plot.

With the mean ($\mu$) and the expected minimum and maximum values specified ($x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$), we'll fix the probability plot to have an intercept of $\mu$ and a slope given by

$$\frac{x_{max}-x_{min}}{\Phi^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{2n})-\Phi^{-1}(\frac{1}{2n})}$$

Next select a subset of $n$ values from $X$ that best match the probability plot by using the Hungarian algorithm.

We can repeat the process for various values of $n$ and select the subset that best meets our requirements (value of $n$, $R^2$ from the probability plot, etc.).

Implemented in R:

```
# OP's data:
x <- c(2.6, 1.1, 3.6, 1.5, 3.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.1, 1.4, 1.1, 2.0, 2.5, 3.1, 2.9,
       3.2, 1.3, 3.5, 2.7, 1.0, 1.7, 4.1, 2.8, 3.2, 3.2, 1.6, 2.0, 3.1, 2.8,
       3.9, 2.0, 3.9, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 2.3, 3.0, 1.9, 2.3, 1.6, 2.7, 1.6, 4.0,
       1.3, 1.1, 2.0, 3.4, 2.6, 2.3, 2.1, 2.3, 1.8, 1.2, 1.8, 3.1, 2.5, 2.2,
       2.9, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8, 4.2, 1.6, 3.3, 2.1, 3.2, 3.1, 1.9, 1.0, 2.0,
       2.2, 1.9, 2.8, 3.6, 2.6, 1.7, 2.6, 1.9, 2.2, 1.6, 4.1, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4,
       2.5, 1.7, 2.7, 1.9, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9, 3.8, 2.6, 1.7, 1.4, 3.7, 1.0, 2.4,
       1.8, 1.2, 1.4, 2.5, 1.4, 3.8, 4.2, 4.3, 3.7, 4.0, 3.0, 1.8, 4.0, 4.2,
       2.8, 2.8, 1.2, 3.3, 2.4, 2.3, 3.0, 1.6, 2.0, 4.5, 2.0, 2.2, 2.1, 2.4,
       1.0, 2.4, 3.6, 2.0, 2.9, 2.0, 4.1, 2.4, 3.1, 2.7, 2.3, 1.4, 1.8, 2.3,
       3.2, 2.8, 1.6, 2.5, 2.9, 1.0, 1.6, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 1.1, 1.8, 3.6, 2.9,
       1.4, 1.2, 3.5, 3.1, 3.4, 3.1, 2.0, 3.3, 2.8, 2.3, 3.6, 3.3, 3.5, 1.7,
       1.3, 1.6, 2.3, 1.3, 2.9, 1.0, 1.3, 1.8, 1.7, 1.3, 3.5, 2.2, 2.2, 3.6,
       3.0, 1.0, 2.5, 2.9, 2.2, 2.4, 2.1, 1.0, 1.3, 2.0, 3.3, 3.1, 3.2, 2.3,
       2.1, 2.7, 3.0, 3.7, 3.1, 2.7, 4.5, 3.0, 1.6, 1.9, 3.1, 3.6, 1.6, 1.2,
       2.0, 1.3, 1.6, 4.7, 2.0, 1.4, 3.6, 2.5, 1.3, 4.0, 1.6, 1.4, 1.9, 3.6,
       2.5, 2.9, 3.7, 2.4, 4.6, 3.7, 2.2, 4.3, 3.7, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 4.0, 4.3,
       3.5, 2.7, 2.0, 2.7, 3.8, 1.3, 3.1, 2.2, 1.8, 1.5, 3.3, 2.9, 1.5, 3.3,
       1.3, 1.7, 2.1, 1.7, 3.0, 2.2, 4.0, 1.3, 4.3, 1.5, 2.5, 2.3, 1.5, 1.6,
       4.4, 1.3, 2.4, 1.8, 2.7, 1.6, 1.5, 3.4, 4.0, 2.5, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 1.6,
       2.8, 1.8, 3.3, 1.7, 1.9, 2.3, 2.4, 3.5, 2.0, 4.3, 1.4, 2.3, 2.8, 3.7,
       4.1, 4.0, 2.7, 2.5, 2.9, 4.1, 2.2, 2.4, 3.0, 1.5, 1.4, 2.0, 2.5, 2.2,
       3.3, 2.2, 1.0, 3.8, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.9, 2.2, 1.4, 1.7, 4.0, 2.3,
       4.4, 2.7, 2.6, 2.7, 3.4, 2.5, 3.9, 2.5, 2.0, 4.3, 2.9, 3.6, 2.0, 1.7,
       2.6, 2.2, 2.2, 3.0, 2.0, 3.3, 1.2, 2.8, 3.2, 4.8, 4.2, 1.6, 1.8, 4.2,
       3.6, 2.4, 3.6, 1.5, 3.0, 3.6, 1.1, 3.1, 2.8, 2.6, 3.8, 2.1, 1.4, 3.3,
       3.0, 3.8, 2.5, 3.8, 2.1, 1.5, 2.7, 2.3, 2.3, 2.2, 2.8, 1.9, 3.7, 3.1,
       2.8, 1.4, 1.8, 3.2)
```

Loading the libraries and defining the functions:

```
library(RcppHungarian)
library(proxy)

bestnorm <- function(x, n, xmin, xmean, xmax) {
  xr <- xmax - xmin
  lapply(
    n,
    function(i) {
      p <- qnorm(seq(1/i/2, 1 - 1/i/2, 1/i))
      y <- xmean + xr*p/diff(p[c(1, i)])
      idx <- HungarianSolver(dist(y, x, method = "euclidean"))$pairs[,2]
      list(
        n = i,
        idx = idx,
        R2 = 1 - sum((x[idx] - y)^2)/sum((x[idx] - mean(x[idx]))^2)
      )
    }
  )
}

ppnorm <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  plot(qnorm(seq(1/n/2, 1 - 1/n/2, 1/n)), sort(x))
}
```

Look at the probability plot $R^2$ values for $n$ varying from 50 to 200:

```
solutions <- bestnorm(x, 50:200, 1, 3, 5)
R2 <- sapply(solutions, "[[", 3)
plot(50:200, R2, xlab = "n")
```

[image]

$R^2$ has a maximum at $n=87$. Show the probability plot and histogram for the subset returned.

```
x2 <- x[solutions[[which.max(R2)]][[2]]]
ppnorm(x2)
hist(x2)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but the probability plot is implausibly straight, much more so than almost any true random sample from a normal distribution.  I wonder if that matters?

Comment: Yeah I think this is a very interesting answer and something I'll consider for simulation, but it definitely comes with a strong caveat that in reality this would make for a very odd duck approach.

Comment: Hard to say if it will matter to the OP. Of course, the subset plotted ($n=87$) is the one that best aligns with the probability plot. The plot for, say, $n=240$ has a believable amount of "wiggle".

Answer (score 2):

You can treat this task as optimization problem. Test statistic is function to optimize (+ penalty for number of removed data points or limit on how many data points to remove), each data point has binary coefficient associated with it (include/exclude). Then you can try greedy solution, random search or some variation of bayesian search (used for hyperparameter tuning). If you examine your test statistic more accurately, maybe you can come up with more efficient search strategy.